# ERROR in node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:27:28 - error TS1005: ']' expected

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to include firebase to my angular app, I import all but when I run `ng serve` I get this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:27:28 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

27     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                              ~~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:27:47 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

27     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                                                 ~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:27:49 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

27     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                                                   ~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:27:50 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

27     [K in keyof T & string as `${Prefix}.${K}`]+?: T[K];
                                                    ~
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.d.ts:28:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

28 };
```

I searched in internet and I found lots of info about this.

I tried to the following:

- Downgrade `@angular/fire` package to `6.1.5`
- Increment typescript version.
- Reinstall `node_modules`.

I tried all of the solutions that I found on the internet, but I don't know how I can solve it.

I use Anguar 10.

This is my `package.json`.

```json
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.4",
    "@datorama/akita-ng-entity-service": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.1.2",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "firebase": "^9.0.2",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.49",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.50.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it myself as follows:

1. I used `@angular/fire 6.1.5` and `firebase 8.10.0`
2. I deleted `node_modules`.
3. I manually added package in `package.json`.
4. Then I reinstalled with `npm install`

Comment: in my case, I also have to delete `package-lock.json` file

Answer (score 13):

It works for me by

```
npm install typescript@latest
```