# Error in node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts when given ng serve

Tags: angular, firebase, version, node-modules, angularfire

I'm facing issue with Firebase package, PFA for `package.json` and error snips.

I tried to downgrade the version of `@angular/fire` from `v7.4` to `v7.0` to make it compatible with angular version 12. got errors in Firebase

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.0",
    "@grammarly/editor-sdk": "^1.8.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.35.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "^4.1.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1134.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "docx": "^7.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "html-to-text": "^8.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-autosize": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^14.0.3",
    "ngx-stripe": "^12.8.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.3.0",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^11.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzS4O.png)

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72024949/11561695